# Create folder based on filename

Tags: bash, files, filesystems, macos, osx-finder

I have a folder with a number of `.png` files, for example:

```
Jeff Smith 1.png
Jeff Donald 1.png
Jeff Donald 2.png
Jeff Smith 2.png
Jeff Roberts.png
Kyle Reds.png
Kyle Reds 1.png
Kyle Blues 1.png
Kyle Blues 2.png
Kyle Person.png
etc 
etc
```

How would I write a bash script that could create a folder for every unique name.

For the example above, we would get folders:

```
Jeff Smith
Jeff Donald
Kyle Reds
Kyle Blues
Kyle Person 
etc
```

I am brand new to bash (and coding in general) - hoping to get some help on this

Thanks

Comment: You'd be better off without any spaces in file or directory names - with spaces they just become harder to deal with. Consider replacing every space with an underscore or similar.

Comment: How should `Carl von Linne.png` be treated?

Comment: you might loop around your list `ls *.png > listefile` & substitude spaces by underscores `_`  & ignore `.png`    with a while loop to build your directories  `while read ; do  mkdir $(echo $REPLY | sed 's/ /_/g;s/.png//') ; done < listefile` for example

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
() { mkdir -p -- ${(u)argv%%( <->|).png}; } *.png
```

Where:

- `() { code; } arguments` is an anonymous function that takes the list of non-hidden `.png` files in the current directory as arguments (accessible as `$argv` or `$@` within the `code`).
- `<->` is the zsh glob operator that matches any sequence of decimal digits (`<first-last>` with neither `first` nor `last` specified).
- `${(u)array-expansion}` expands to the unique elements (removes duplicates) of the array expansion.
- `${array%%pattern}` expands to the elements of the array stripped of the longest string at the end that matches the `pattern`.

So, here, we're making a directory for each unique string made of the png files stripped of an optional `" <digits>"` followed by `.png`.

With `bash` and GNU tools, you could do something similar with:

```
#! /bin/bash -
export LC_ALL=C # needed for sed to deal with arbitrary byte values, for
                # [0-9] to match on 0123456789 only and for sort -u to report
                # unique records as opposed to one of several that sort the
                # same.

shopt -s failglob # to properly handle the cases where there's no png
set -o pipefail   # ditto, to report a failure exit status in that case.

printf '%s\0' *.png |
  sed -Ez 's/( [0-9]+)?\.png$//' |
  sort -zu |
  xargs -r0 mkdir -p --
```

Or avoiding GNUisms and with bash 4+:

```
#! /bin/bash -
shopt -s failglob extglob
typeset -A unique
files=(*.png) || exit
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
  file=${file%.png}
  file=${file% +([0123456789])}
  unique[$file]=
done
mkdir -p -- "${!unique[@]}"
```

Note that if there a file called `" 12.png"` for instance in the current directory, that would result in an empty directory name. In that last `bash` solution above, that would cause a syntax errors as `bash` associative arrays don't support elements with an empty key, and in all others, you'd get an error by `mkdir` which would not be able to create a directory with an empty name.

Note that macos doesn't come with GNU tools by default, and it comes with a very older version of `bash`. It has always been coming with `zsh` though. If you have to use `bash` there and can't install newer versions nor GNU tools, you could resort to `perl` instead:

```
#! /bin/bash -
perl -e '
  for (<*.png>) {
    s/\.png\z//;
    s/ \d+\z//;
    $unique{$_} = undef;
  }
  $ret = 0;
  for (keys %unique) {
    unless (mkdir($_) || ($!{EEXIST} && -d $_)) {
      warn "Cannot create $_: $!\n";
      $ret = 1;
    }
  }
  exit $ret;'
```

(though there's nothing `bash`-specific in that code which should work with the `sh` of any system, provided `perl` is installed).